# Create Modal View with Save/Cancel button

Tags: ios, swift, segue, xcode-storyboard

I'm pretty new to Xcode development (I'm using swift), and am building up my application flow in the storyboard. I'm attempting to create an "Add New" dialog in a similar style to that on the Calendar app.

In terms of structure, I have a `UITableViewController` that has a  `UINavigationItem` on it (There is a `UINavigationController` before it in the storyboard. I have added a `UIBarButtonItem` with the Add Identifier, and created a Segue from it to a new `UIViewController`, using the "Present Modally" option to make the view appear in from the bottom.

[image: Storyboard Layout]

On the "Add New" screen, I want to have a Navigation Bar at the top, with a Cancel Button, a Save Button and the page title (the same way the Calendar App Add Event view works).

Initially I figured I would just throw a UIToolBar item onto the page and create those items by hand. However, the apple standards seem to indicate that Toolbars should only ever appear at the bottom of the screen, not the top.

I can change the Segue to "Show", this causes the view to slide in from the right. It also sets the left hand button to a "Back" action (i.e. "

What is the apple-approved structure I should be using to do this? To summarise, I want to do the following:

- Segue from the Add button on the List View to the Add View.
- Animate the Add View in from the bottom
- Display a Navigation Bar on the Add View containing three items:

  - Cancel (Far Left) - Returns to the Previous View (by sliding the view down)
  - Title (Middle)
  - Save (Far Right) - Performs a custom action (I can handle this myself)

Comment: Apple gives you guidelines, but they can be broken.  Their goal is to have all iOS apps follow a similar design which would make it easy on their users.  Your goal is to make a nice, intuitive app. If you feel it's better to have it presented as a modal, go for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should present the "Add New" dialog inside another UINavigationController, even if you don't intent to push additional view controllers onto it once it is presented. This allows you to easily use navigation items again to show the buttons.

Comment: You mean segue to a new NavigationController view? One that is used by the Modal View only?

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the advice. So I guess I'd need to manually program the Cancel button to return to the correct view?

Comment: See [Dismissing Presented View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW14). Basically you want to come up with a way for the presented view controller to let the presenting view controller know that the user chose to cancel. Then the presenting view controller would dismiss it.